# Keeping Subnav active on corresponding page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

Ok so i am building a theme for in wordpress. However i cannot figure out how to do this. How do i keep the subnav active on the corresponding page? For example you click on the drop down subnav, click a subnav link and it stays open on the corresponding page, showing the user where they are on the website. thanks for your help.

The nav is here?
http://uhuruchild.phpfogapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.current-menu-ancestor{background-color: #000000;}
```

this will work

see the documentation [wordpress nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Current-Page_Menu_Items)